# Play: Cannot resolve symbol PlaySpecification

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

I cannot import PlaySpecification.
First, it seems to be part of Specs2, but after importing specs2 it doesnt'show up.
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#playspecification

On the other hand here it says it's part or play.api.test, but I cannot  find it either
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.PlaySpecification

Does anyone can tell me how I can import PlaySpecification?

I've tried with both configurations in build.sbt, and none of them works:

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.9.5" % "test",
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-mock" % "3.9.5" % "test"
```

and

```
specs2 % Test
```

Comment: Adding the dependency as explained in my answer should resolve this. If you are using an IDE, you probably need to refresh/re-import the project. So, what do you mean by not being able to import `PlaySpecification`?

Comment: Thx. Now it works, not sure what's happening!

Comment: Okay. I think you can accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += specs2 % Test
```

After that, if you are using an IDE, refresh the project.